# Replacing unrecognized character from file using TCL

Tags: tcl

I am writing a script to read a file and replace some characters which includes unrecognized characters like

```
"^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H"
```

Actually this file was generated by redirecting the console output of a telnet session. I want to remove this character. I have to remove **"--More---"** from the file.

I gave a try on replacing them using

```
set fileID [open "bar" r]
set temp [open "temp.txt" w+]
while {[eof $fileID] != 1} {
    gets $fileID lineInfo
    regsub -all "More" $lineInfo "" lineInfo
    regsub -all "--More--" $lineInfo "" lineInfo  #This is not working
    puts $temp $lineInfo
}
```

I can remove "More", but i am not able to remove "--More--". Can anybody explain this ?

I also tried like

```
regsub -all "^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H" $lineInfo "" lineInfo  #This is also not working
```

This also not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write `^H` as `\u0008`…

Comment: `string map` might be easier for simple replacements too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recomment to use the `:print:` character class in your regex to match all "sensible" characters — refer to the [`re_syntax` manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M31).

The resulting call to `regsub` should replace all non-printable characters with empty strings, so we use a negated character class (via `^`), and so the proper incantation would look like this:

```
set lineInfo [regsub -all {[^[:print:]]} $lineInfo ""]
```

As to removing "--More--"" — I have two hypotheses:

- `regsub` is confused treating `--More--` as a switch as it starts with a dash.  This can be easily fixed by passing `--` to `regsub` after all the switches — see the [manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regsub.htm#M12).
- Your "--More--" as it appears in the file is not really a solid string, and it has certain non-printable characters embedded into it.  The usual approach to debugging such situations is inspecting the file usina a HEX-dumper like `xxd` or a HEX-editor/viewer.

Comment: If possible, it's worth trying to get the data from the remote side without mangling it through a pager like `more`…